# How do I flip the 2D plots of this Python code using numpy.transpose()?

Tags: python, numpy

My friend and I wrote the following code to solve partial differential equations:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.sparse.linalg as la
import gc
import time

#%%
h = 0.1
const = 1
dt1 = 0.25*0.99*h**2
dt2 = 0.1
dt3 = 0.001

Nt_1 = int(40.0/dt1+1)
Nt_2 = int(40.0/dt2+1)
Nt_3 = int(40.0/dt3+1)

t_1 = np.linspace(0,40.0,Nt_1)
t_2 = np.linspace(0,40.0,Nt_2)
t_3 = np.linspace(0,40.0,Nt_3)


xbegin = 0
xend = 16
ybegin = 0
yend = 8

Sx = xend-xbegin
Sy = yend-xbegin

Nx = int(Sx/h+1)
Ny = int(Sy/h+1)
Np = (Nx-2)*(Ny-2)

I = sp.eye(Np,Np,format='csc')


def meshcreator(xb,xe,yb,ye):
    meshy1,meshx1 = np.mgrid[yb+h:ye:h,xb+h:xe:h]
    return meshy1,meshx1

def Matrixmaker(Nx3,Ny3):

    Dx = 1/h*(sp.diags([-1, 1], [-1, 0], shape=(Nx3-1, Nx3-2),format='csc'))
    Dy = 1/h*(sp.diags([-1, 1], [-1, 0], shape=(Ny3-1, Ny3-2),format='csc'))
    Dx_t = Dx.transpose()
    Dy_t = Dy.transpose()

    Lxx = Dx_t.dot(Dx)
    Lyy = Dy_t.dot(Dy)

    Ix = sp.eye(Nx3-2)
    Iy = sp.eye(Ny3-2)

    L = sp.kron(Iy,Lxx) + sp.kron(Lyy,Ix)
    L = -L

    return L
#%%
def k_maker(h1,Nx1,Ny1,q):
    meshy2,meshx2 = meshcreator(xbegin,xend,ybegin,yend)

#    k1 = sp.lil_matrix((Ny1-2, Nx1-2)).toarray()
    k1 = np.zeros((Ny1-2,Nx1-2))
    for i in range(len(meshx2[:,0])): 
        for j in range(len(meshx2[0,:])):
            if 1 <= meshx2[i,j] <= 2 and 1 <= meshy2[i,j] <= 2:
                k1[i,j] = q
            elif 1 <= meshx2[i,j] <= 3 and 3 <= meshy2[i,j] <= 5:
                k1[i,j] = q
            elif 4 <= meshx2[i,j] <= 7 and 4 <= meshy2[i,j] <= 7:
                k1[i,j] = q
            elif 9 <= meshx2[i,j] <= 12 and 4 <= meshy2[i,j] <= 6:
                k1[i,j] = q
            elif 13 <= meshx2[i,j] <= 15 and 1 <= meshy2[i,j] <= 3:
                k1[i,j] = q

    return k1, meshx2, meshy2


k,meshx,meshy = k_maker(h,Nx,Ny,const)
plt.figure(4)
plt.spy(k,aspect='equal')

k = k.reshape((Np,1))
#%%

def ut0(x,y):
    return (np.exp(-2*(x-1.5)**2-2*(y-1.5)**2).reshape(Np))



def jacobian(L2,value):
    value2 = k*value
    u_diag = sp.diags(diagonals = [np.reshape(value2,(Np))],offsets=[0],shape=(Np,Np),format='csc')
    jacob = L2 + sp.diags(diagonals = [k.reshape(Np)],offsets=[0],shape=(Np,Np),format='csc') - 2*u_diag
    return jacob


#%%

A = Matrixmaker(Nx,Ny)

ut0 = (ut0(meshx,meshy).reshape(Np,1))


def FE_BE_iterator(L3,u1,u0,timestep,Nt,choice,t,eps1 = 10e-3): 

        def f1(uk):
            return L3*uk 
        def f2(uk):
            return k*uk
        def f3(uk):
            utmp = uk*uk
            return k*utmp
        def F0(uk):
            return f1(uk)+f2(uk)-f3(uk)
        errorlist = []
        usollist = [u0]
        count = 0


        if choice == 'Forward':
            timerstart = time.time()
            for i in range(Nt):
                usol = timestep*(F0(u0))+u0
                u0 = usol

                if abs(t[i]-1) <= timestep and count == 0:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count +=1
                if abs(t[i]-2) <= timestep and count == 1:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-3) <= timestep and count == 2:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-5) <= timestep and count == 3:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-10) <= timestep and count == 4:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-20) <= timestep and count == 5:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1                
                if abs(t[i]-40) <= timestep and count == 6:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
            timerend = time.time()
            time_elapsed = timerend-timerstart
            print("Time elapsed for " + choice + " = ", time_elapsed)
            return usollist,errorlist

        if choice == 'Newton':

            timerstart = time.time()
            for i in range(Nt):
                residual = 1
                while residual > eps1:
                    jac = jacobian(L3,u1)
                    S = I-jac*timestep
                    RHS = u1-u0-timestep*F0(u1)
                    v = (la.spsolve(S,RHS)).reshape(Np,1)
                    ukp1 = u1-v
                    u1 = ukp1
                    residual = np.linalg.norm(v)
                    errorlist.append(residual)

                usol = timestep*(F0(ukp1)) + u0
                u0 = usol

                if abs(t[i]-1) <= timestep and count == 0:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count +=1
                if abs(t[i]-2) <= timestep and count == 1:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-3) <= timestep and count == 2:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-5) <= timestep and count == 3:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-10) <= timestep and count == 4:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-20) <= timestep and count == 5:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1                
                if abs(t[i]-40) <= timestep and count == 6:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1        
            timerend = time.time()
            time_elapsed = timerend-timerstart
            print("Time elapsed for " + choice + " = ", time_elapsed)
            return usollist,errorlist


        if choice == 'Picard':
            timerstart = time.time()
            for i in range(Nt):
                usol = u0
                residual = 1
                while residual > eps1:
                    usol = timestep*F0(usol) + u0
                    residual = np.linalg.norm(usol-timestep*F0(usol)-u0)
                u0 = usol

                if abs(t[i]-1) <= timestep and count == 0:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count +=1
                if abs(t[i]-2) <= timestep and count == 1:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-3) <= timestep and count == 2:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-5) <= timestep and count == 3:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-10) <= timestep and count == 4:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
                if abs(t[i]-20) <= timestep and count == 5:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1                
                if abs(t[i]-40) <= timestep and count == 6:
                    usollist.append(usol.reshape(Np,1))
                    count+=1
            timerend = time.time()
            time_elapsed = timerend-timerstart
            print("Time elapsed for " + choice + " = ", time_elapsed)
            return usollist,errorlist


def plot(M,start,startp1,stepdt,N_t,name,t_time):
    Solution1 = FE_BE_iterator(M,start,startp1,stepdt,N_t,name,t_time)
    Solution = Solution1[0]
    Error = Solution1[1]

    for s in range(len(Solution)):
        plt.subplot(2,4,s+1)
        plt.imshow((Solution[s]).reshape((Nx-2,Ny-2),order ='F'),origin='lower',extent=(ybegin,yend,xbegin,xend))
        plt.colorbar()

    if name == 'Newton':
        plt.figure(0)
        plt.plot(Error)

counter = 0
for j in ['Forward','Newton','Picard']:
    plt.figure(counter+1)
    if j == 'Forward':
        plot(A,ut0,ut0,dt1,Nt_1,j,t_1)
    elif j == 'Newton':
        plot(A,ut0,ut0,dt2,Nt_2,j,t_2)
    elif j == 'Picard':
        plot(A,ut0,ut0,dt3,Nt_3,j,t_3)
    counter+=1

gc.collect()
```

This produces plots such as this one:
[image: Flipped plot]

Whereas I'd like to have them look like this:

[image: Desired Plot]

I know the solution vector in the `imshow` function should be transposed, but transposing it just messes up my solution and doesn't rotate the image. How do I fix it?

EDIT: Here's what my attempt at rotating the image using the transpose gives:
[image: Distorted solution]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'messes up my solution'? You're correct that `plt.imshow(arr.T)` should do what you want... so why doesn't it exactly? (Make sure you do it after the reshape.)

Comment: @kwinkunks I use 

```plt.imshow(((Solution[s]).reshape((Nx-2,Ny-2),order ='F')).T,origin='lower',extent=(ybegin,yend,xbegin,xend))```



However, the solution on the grid is just distorted, while my axes haven't been rotated. I'll post a picture for clarification.

Comment: The images themselves look correct to me -- you just need to adjust the aspect ratios; `plt.imshow()` has an `aspect` kwarg. And I guess you need to flip the `extent` around, because it goes `(left, right, bottom, top)` (you have y-axis first I think).